# Rewriting all icons to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I've written the below code but I don't think its very efficient, but when I put a not ("!") www
line in, the variable is not carried through to the rule.  Any help would be much appreciated:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|ico|png|tif|tiff|webp)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://ico.%1/favicon.png [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)favicon\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|ico|png|tif|tiff|webp)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://ico.%{HTTP_HOST}/favicon.png [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.ico$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://ico.%1/$1.ico [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.ico$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://ico.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.ico [R=301,L,NC]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question isn't clear or specific.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, what's your exact question here? Kindly do clarify on same, thank you.

Comment: Why are you _redirecting_ (not "rewriting") all icons to a subdomain? (Yes, this is not very efficient and should be unnecessary.) And the 2nd and 4th rules are entirely redundant.